# self signed certificate in certificate chain node js?

Tags: gmail, nodes, nodemailer

code snippet for nodemailer and gmail

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        // service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'mail_id', 
            pass: 'password'
        }

});
```

Please help find the mistake for solving the issue - self signed certificate in certificate chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You want reconfigure your code like below**

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
```

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        // service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'your mail_id', 
            pass: 'Your password'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }));